# Working with Multiple cores

Tags: solr, lucene

I have 2 cores, ***core1*** and ***core2*** and I am trying to achieve following things with multiple cores.
1)  How to delete all entries from core1 (only core1).
Generally I was using following command to delete all documents when I was having only one core.
java -Ddata=args -Dcommit=true -jar post.jar "*:*"

2) Using Nutch, how to index web documents only in core2. (not in core1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each core will have a separate Url (see below for an example). Just reference each core separately for your delete and index operations.

- `http://localhost:8983/solr/core1`
- `http://localhost:8983/solr/core2`

1) For deleting I would recommend using the [Delete by ID or Query](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages#A.22delete.22_documents_by_ID_and_by_Query) option that can be executed via curl, specifying the url for core1.

2) For indexing to core2 with Nutch, just use the appropriate url for core2 in the indexing step.

Comment: For some reason my curl command was giving me error. I corrected it and now it is working fine problem 1.
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/core1/update/?commit=true -H "Content-Type: text/xml" -d "<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>"

Comment: Thanks Paige for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Problem 1:
For some reason my curl command was giving me error. 
I corrected it and now it is working fine.

```
 curl localhost:8983/solr/core1/update/?commit=true -H "Content-Type: text/xml" -d "<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>
```

Problem 2:
For indexing data to different cores using Nutch, I used following command and it worked for me. Hence thought sharing with you.

```
bin/nutch crawl urls -solr http://localhost:8983/solr/core1/ -depth 3 -topN 5

bin/nutch crawl urls -solr http://localhost:8983/solr/core2/ -depth 3 -topN 5
```